# am I right about what these XPath expressions mean?

Tags: xpath

this is for school, if you know your XPath and wouldn't mind telling me if I'm correct:

1.
`//a[/b]/a`

every 'a' that has a parent 'a' in a tree where the root is 'b'. (the location of the `[/b]` is irrelevant? i.e. is the above equivalent to `//a/a[/b]` ?

2.
`//*[//a]//a[/a][a]`

breaking it down from left to right:
`//*[//a]` means all elements having a descendant 'a',
therefore `//*[//a]//a` (quite school-excerisely) means all 'a' elements.
and `//*[//a]//a[/a]` means all 'a' elements in a tree where the root is 'a',
and finally - `//*[//a]//a[/a][a]` means all 'a' elements in a tree where the root is 'a' that have a child 'a'.

Thanks for any help, can't seem to get a straight answer anywhere.

Comment: finally a homework question that actually shows the person asking has done some work on it. +1 for that.

Comment: You are mostly correct.  With regards to #2, `//*[//a]` doesn't select all elements that have a descendant `a`, it selects all elements if the document contains an `a` any where within the document.  In order to select all elements with a descendant `a` you need to make the predicate filter relative to the matched element: `//*[.//a]`

Comment: okay, so is it true that the position of any predicate of the form [//a],[/a] is irrelevant?
How about a plain [a], does the position of that matter?
Thanks! (Stack Overflow is seriously a phenomenon)

Comment: That's right. It doesn't really make sense to have absolute paths (paths starting with a slash) inside of square brackets. You can do it but you'd never find such a thing in real world XPath expressions.

Comment: A plain [a] does matter where you put it. It selects the elements that contain an `a` child element where it is applied.  Think of the square brackets as the equivalent of an SQL WHERE clause. e.g. `//*[a]` reads "select all elements that have a child element named `a`" and `//a/a[b]` reads "select all `a` elements that are children of `a` elements and have a child element named `b`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What class is quizzing you on arcane XPath queries? Wow.

1. `//a[/b]/a`
   Yes, you have that right. The location of `[/b]` is irrelevant.
2. `//*[//a]//a[/a][a]`
   Technically `//*[//a]//a` is equivalent to `//*//a` which means all 'a' elements which have an ancestor element. So if the root element is 'a' it won't won't match. Aside from that, yes, your analysis is correct.

For what it's worth, a few years ago I implemented a full XPath parser from scratch in JavaScript for a project I worked on. So I really hope my answers are right!

Comment: Thanks (I put in a comment above).
It's a silly class about Search Engines where they cover too much at too shallow of a level :)